# Get InnerShadow for Custom View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to make a custom chronometer
here is my code this is wrking perfectly
The problem am stic with is i want to have inner shadow

public class CustomChronometer extends Chronometer {

```
private boolean start = false;
private long startTime, elapsedTime;
private float angle = 0f;
private Paint paint, p;
private RectF r;

public CustomChronometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0897ef"));
    paint.setStrokeWidth(25);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);

//      paint.setStrokeCap(Cap.ROUND);



}

@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
        int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    r = new RectF(left + 30, top + 30, right - 30, bottom - 30);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (start) {
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        angle = (elapsedTime - startTime) * 0.006f;
        canvas.drawArc(r, 270f, angle, false, paint);
        if (angle >= 360) {
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            angle = 0f;
        }
        invalidate();
    }

}

@Override
public void start() {
    super.start();
    start = true;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Override
public void stop() {
    super.stop();
    start = false;
}
}
```

[image]

I require it to look like this

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to add the same type of shadow.

Comment: Yes, try this in paint   paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0897ef"));
  paint.setStrokeWidth(40);
  paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  paint.setAntiAlias(true);
  paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(7, Blur.INNER)); also the hardware acceleartion should be disabled from  manifest

Comment: Thanks. You should write this as an answer and accept it. :)

Comment: yeah ill do it later..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
paint paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0897ef"));
paint.setStrokeWidth(40);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setAntiAlias(true); 
paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(7, Blur.INNER));
```

also the hardware acceleration should be disabled from manifest –

Comment: Why have I to disable "hardware acceleration"? Is it possible without disabling?